# My models have disconnected from their armatures and have gone into an A-pose. Is there anyway to to automatically reconnect them?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, pose-mode

I booted up Blender and found that all my models had reverted to an A-pose despite their respective skeletons still being posed. I am not sure whether Blender has automatically updated because I cant remember which version I was running; however I am now using 2.93 LTS.

The model and rig was one I imported as I don't know how to make it myself in Blender, however I have never had any issues with it. This is for a University project so any help asap is appreciated.

[image: Scene in question with A-posed Models]
[image: Assets in collection]

Comment: wht does it give if you parent your object to the armature with Ctrl P > Armature Deform?

Comment: It moves my model into the centre of the scene and rescales it but leaves the armature where it is.

Comment: could you please share a file with just one character object + its armature? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've just uploaded it for you, I think I've done it right.

Comment: please once you've uploaded, copy paste here the URL it has generated

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d013a97ffbad4e9bb46912390ab97d53

Answer (score 0):

Reset the rotation of the armature with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, rotate it -90° on X, apply its rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*,  apply its scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*, in Pose mode reset its pose with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Unparent the character object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*, apply its rotation and scale, parent it *With Automatic Weights*. It will still need some weight painting (not sure you can avoid that).

Comment: That hasn’t worked in reattaching my model to the armature.

Comment: It works here, note that your character objects have lost their vertex groups so as I say you need to reparent With Automatic Weights